# $\sqrt{x}=-1$. How can I solve it?

Tags: complex-numbers, multivalued-functions

I am so curious about this equation:
$\sqrt{x}=-1$

1. Does the $x$ where $x\in \mathbb{C}$ exist?
2. How can I solve it?

Comment: Remember that $\;i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ . You can also decide to take the *negative* real root, so $\;\sqrt1=-1\;$ ...non-standard but possible.

Comment: There is no solution. If some $x$ satisfied this, then, necessarily, $x=(-1)^2$. But then $x=1$, which would mean $\sqrt{1} = -1$, contradiction.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 : are you sure it is a contradiction ?

Comment: @user1952009 Hmm, well do you think there's something incorrect with what I said?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 :  I thought we could choose $\sqrt{r e^{i \theta}} = \sqrt{r} e^{i \theta / 2}$, what about $1 = e^{2 i \pi}$ ?

Comment: $\sqrt{ }$ normally indicates the principal square root.

Comment: in my opinion, the question is a bit too broad - what is the context of your struggle?

Comment: @DietrichBurde If you square both sides, don't you get $-1 = (-1)^2 = 1$....?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I meant squaring $\sqrt{1}=-1$ gives no contradiction.

Comment: @fqq : for positive real numbers, not complex numbers ?! i.e. what is the $\sqrt{}$ of $e^{2 i \pi}$ ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes but $\sqrt{1}$ is the principal root. It is not multivalued; its value is unambiguously equal to $1$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 No, $\sqrt{1}$ is not necessarily the principal root.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 uhm well that is certainly how I interpret it if I know $x \in \mathbb R$. If i know we are talking about complex numbers, every square root is multivalued (as it should be)

Comment: well writing that sometimes $\sqrt{1} \ne \sqrt{1}$ I admit is not very nice :)

Comment: Do you mean square root or principal square root ?

Answer (score 2):

This shows you how to work with this problems for a general $n$-th root
Let $x = \rho (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$.

Then $$\sqrt x = \sqrt \rho (\cos \left(\frac{\theta + 2k\pi}{2}\right) + i \sin(\cos \left(\frac{\theta + 2k\pi}{2}\right)$$

for $k = 0,1$. That is $\sqrt x$ is not a single number but rather a set of two numbers, one for each value of $k$. Now, since you want $\sqrt x = -1 = 1 (\cos (\pi) + i \sin \pi)$, you need $\rho = 1$. Then you get either $\frac \theta 2 = \pi \implies \theta = 2\pi$ or $\frac{\theta}2 + \pi = \pi \implies \theta = 0$. Therefore the two solutions are

$$x = 1 (\cos 2\pi + i \sin 2\pi) = 1$$
$$x = 1 (\cos 0 + i \sin 0) = 1$$

So there is the unique solution in $\mathbb C$, that is $\sqrt 1 = -1$
Or better: $$ -1 \in \sqrt 1 = \{-1, 1\}$$ since the latter is a set

Comment: I disagree with $\sqrt x$ not denoting a function.

Comment: @YvesDaoust good to know! :-)

Comment: What is the meaning of $\sqrt x=-1$ if $\sqrt x$ is a set ? I would expect $\sqrt x\ni-1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust abuse of notation. I interpreted it as $-1 \in \sqrt x$

Answer (score 0):

The equation $\sqrt{x}=-1$ implies that $x^2=1$, so necessarily $x=1$ or $x=-1$. Certainly $x=-1$ is not a solution, because $\sqrt{-1}$ is not a real number, hence different from $-1$.
On the other hand, $x=1$ is only a solution if we choose the negative square root, i.e., $\sqrt{1}=-1$. Whether or not this is a valid solution, depends on the definition of $\sqrt{}$. For complex numbers, certainly it need not be the principal square root. And the OP asks for complex solutions.

Comment: I think most mathematicians use $\sqrt{1}=1$

Comment: @Henry For complex numbers, $\log$, $\sqrt{}$, etc. are multivalued, as you know.

Comment: "The equation $\sqrt{x}=−1$ implies that $x^2=1$" -- in fact, it implies that $x = 1$, saving you a part of your response.

Comment: No, $\sqrt x=-1$ implies $x=1$.

Comment: Dear downvoters, please explain me what is wrong with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume the complex solution

$$\sqrt{x+iy}=-1.$$

By squaring,

$$x+iy=1=1\cdot e^{i0}$$

is the only possibility.

Then the principal value of the square root is

$$\sqrt{x+iy}=\sqrt1\cdot e^{i0/2}, $$ which doesn't fit.

---

Had the principal branch be defined as

$$\sqrt z=\sqrt\rho e^{i\theta/2+i\pi},$$
then $x+iy=1$ would have been a solution.

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that squaring is killing some solutions.

Comment: (p.s. my previous comment was not related to the downvote)

Comment: @marco: no, squaring kills no solution. On the opposite, it is able to introduce extra ones. Compare $a=b\to a^2=b^2$ and $a-b=0\to(a+b)(a-b)=0$.

Comment: Please downvoters, show me what is wrong.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I guess that most people would interpret it as killing solutions, and rightly so. With your method, $z^{1/n} = 1 \implies z = 1$, which is of course not the only solutions. Now you can argue that $z^{1/2}$ and $\sqrt z$ are different because in the latter you chose a particular branch, but I don't think this is a standard way to work and in any case it is a matter of taste, so no real discussion can go on there. Finally, one would guess that the quesiton $\sqrt x = -1$ would be trivial if you define $\sqrt x$ as the principal branch, right? But then again, who knows

Comment: @ant: indeed some of this discussion is pointless as $\sqrt x$ can be interpreted differently. Anyway, there is no solution killing, $z^{1/n}=1\implies z=1$ *always*; that doesn't mean that $(z^{1/n})^n$ has a single solution in $z^{1/n}$.